# Tips on making a sauce out of beef trimmings.

Tags: sauce, beef

I have trimmings from a Beef tenderloin and would rather not throw them away. I already have a demi being made and will be making a sauce with cremini, onion, garlic and red wine.

Tips on handling the trimmings?

Comment: "already have a demi being made" - are you looking to include the trimmings in this or the sauce you also mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are meat (not fat, connective tissue etc.), I'd
**mince them to approximate a butcher's coarse grind, sear them briefly in recovered fat or a neutral-tasting oil (for a chewy texture in small bits) and add them to the demi-glaze.**  (If you have a food processor, pulsing them *briefly* will work; though that's more cleanup.)

Serving suggestion: serve over oven roasted potatoes (or other root veggies, such as parsnips or even beets.)